VS Code to Google Colab transition tensorflow
I have written a code in VSCode using tensorflow library that trains a model to detect road lanes. I have used the Road Line and Marking Dataset for training. It worked perfectly fine in VS Code but I wanted to transition to colab to make it faster. I am getting a lot of value errors like this:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 126>()
124
125 # Training loop
--> 126 detect = model.fit(
127     load_dataset_batch(extracted_trains_folder, extracted_labels_folder, batch_size),
128     steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
13                 try:
14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
16                 except:
17                     do_return = False
ValueError: in user code:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1384, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1373, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1150, in train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/input_spec.py", line 253, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_15' (type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "conv2d_105" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)

Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_15' (type Sequential):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
  • training=True
  • mask=None

I tried debugging the code, but it didn't help me much.
This is the entire code:
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab import drive
import zipfile
import math

drive.mount('/content/drive')

def extract_zip(zip_path, extract_path):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(extract_path)

def load_dataset_batch(trains_folder, labels_folder, batch_size):
    train_filenames = sorted(os.listdir(trains_folder))
    label_filenames = sorted(os.listdir(labels_folder))
    num_samples = len(train_filenames)

    for start_idx in range(0, num_samples, batch_size):
        end_idx = min(start_idx + batch_size, num_samples)

        images_batch = []
        annotations_batch = []

        for train_filename, label_filename in zip(train_filenames[start_idx:end_idx], label_filenames[start_idx:end_idx]):
            if train_filename.endswith('.jpg') and label_filename.endswith('.png'):
                train_image_path = os.path.join(trains_folder, train_filename)
                label_image_path = os.path.join(labels_folder, label_filename)

                train_image = cv2.imread(train_image_path)
                train_image = cv2.resize(train_image, (256, 256))

                label_image = cv2.imread(label_image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                label_image = cv2.resize(label_image, (256, 256))

                images_batch.append(train_image)
                annotations_batch.append(label_image)

        images_batch = np.array(images_batch) / 255.0
        annotations_batch = np.array(annotations_batch)

        masks = []
        for annotation in annotations_batch:
            mask = np.zeros((annotation.shape[0], annotation.shape[1], num_classes), dtype=np.uint8)
            for i in range(num_classes):
                mask[:, :, i] = (annotation == i)
            masks.append(mask)
        masks = np.array(masks)

        yield images_batch, masks

def preprocess_data(images, annotations):
    # Preprocess images (e.g., resize, normalize)
    images = [cv2.resize(image, (256, 256)) for image in images]
    images = np.array(images) / 255.0
    
    # Preprocess annotations to create multi-class masks
    masks = []
    for annotation in annotations:
        # Convert grayscale annotation to multi-class mask
        mask = np.zeros((annotation.shape[0], annotation.shape[1], num_classes), dtype=np.uint8)
        for i in range(num_classes):
            mask[:, :, i] = (annotation == i)
        masks.append(mask)
    
    return images, masks

def create_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=input_shape),
        
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
        
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
        
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
        
        tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
        
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
        
        tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
        
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
        
        tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
        
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_classes, (1, 1), activation='softmax', padding='same')
    ])
    return model

# Define paths to dataset in Google Drive
base_folder = '/content/drive/My Drive/datasets/lane_detection'
zip_trains_path = os.path.join(base_folder, 'trains.zip')
zip_labels_path = os.path.join(base_folder, 'labels.zip')
csv_path = os.path.join(base_folder, 'classes.csv')

# Extract zip folders to Colab's temporary directory
extracted_trains_folder = '/content/trains'
extracted_labels_folder = '/content/labels'

extract_zip(zip_trains_path, extracted_trains_folder)
extract_zip(zip_labels_path, extracted_labels_folder)

# Number of classes in the dataset
num_classes = 25

# Model creation
input_shape = (256, 256, 3)
model = create_model(input_shape, num_classes)

# Compile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Calculate total number of samples
total_samples = len(os.listdir(extracted_trains_folder))

# Define batch size and steps per epoch
batch_size = 4
steps_per_epoch = math.ceil(total_samples / batch_size)

# Train model with batch processing

# Training loop
detect = model.fit(
    load_dataset_batch(extracted_trains_folder, extracted_labels_folder, batch_size),
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    epochs=10
)

# Plot training & validation accuracy values
plt.plot(detect.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(detect.history.get('val_accuracy', []))
plt.title('Model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

# Plot training & validation loss values
plt.plot(detect.history['loss'])
plt.plot(detect.history.get('val_loss', []))
plt.title('Model loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()



https://pastebin.com/raw/tmR8BL0t
